# Coroutine and Callback handler in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am currently building an app using AWS SDK. One of the API is a sign in and is requiring, in addition to email and password, a Callback in order to get back the status of the request. The issue is that I am not able to send back the result.

This is my code:

```
override suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Result<SignInResult> =
        withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            try {
                api.signIn(email, password, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
                    override fun onResult(result: SignInResult?) {
                        Result.Success(result!!)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                        Result.Error(e!!)
                    }
                })
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Result.Error(e)
            }
        }
```

The issue is that coroutine sign in is requiring a return of `Result` but I do not know what to return because I should only return when `onResult`, `onError` and when catching an exception.

Any idea how to make it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to work with callbacks:

```
override suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Result<SignInResult> = 
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        try {
            api.signIn(email, password, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
                override fun onResult(result: SignInResult) {
                    // Resume coroutine with a value provided by the callback
                    continuation.resumeWith(Result.Success(result))
                }

                override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                    continuation.resumeWith(Result.Error(e))
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            continuation.resumeWith(Result.Error(e))
        }
    }
```

[`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) suspends coroutine in which it executed until we decide to continue by calling appropriate methods - `Continuation.resume...`. `suspendCoroutine` mainly used when we have some legacy code with callbacks.

There is also [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) builder function, it behaves similar to `suspendCoroutine` with additional feature - provides an implementation of `CancellableContinuation` to the block.

Comment: Hey @Seb, does my answer work for you?